# Add a text input to Streamlit tree select

Tags: python, streamlit

From the [Streamlit tree select package](https://github.com/Schluca/streamlit_tree_select) , the tree select is created but I need user to fill up text if “Others” were checked. The input text of Others is display above the tree-select (supposed display below the “Trading”) as shown in the picture below.

Is there any way I can display it in correct location? If this is not possible, what is the other ways where I can created tree select like selection and enable input text in "Others"?

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_gsheets import GSheetsConnection
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit_authenticator as stauth
from streamlit_tree_select import tree_select

nodes = [
           {"label": "Material Supplier", "value": "Material Supplier"},
           {
               "label": "Service Supplier",
               "value": "Service Supplier",
               "children": [
                   {"label": "Automation", "value": "Automation"},
                   {"label": "Engineering", "value": "Engineering"},
                   {"label": "Logistics", "value": "Logistics"},
                   {"label": "Management", "value": "Management"},
                   {"label": "Consulting", "value": "Consulting"},
                   {"label": "Trading", "value": "Trading"},  
                   {"label":"Others","value": st.text_input(label="Others",key="1")}, 
               ],
           },
           {
               "label": "Steel User",
               "value": "Steel User",
               "children": [
                   {"label": "Roll Formers", "value": "Roll Formers"},
                   {"label": "Coil Service Centres", "value": "Coil Service Centres"},
                   {"label": "Fabricators", "value": "Fabricators"}, 
                   #{"label":"Others","value": st.text_input(label="Others",key="2")}, 
               ],
           },]
return_select = tree_select(nodes)
st.write(return_select)
```

[image]